# How to change docstring of TestCase Class in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testcase, docstring

In Python 2.5 (Jython actually), for the UnitTest TestCase Class - there's is no SetUpClass method, and `__init__` is not really acceptable (no refference to self).
When I try to change docstring inside the TestCase:

```
import os
fileName = os.path.split(__file__)[1]
testCaseName = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]
setattr(__name__, '__doc__', testCaseName)
```

I'm getting:

```
setattr(__name__, '__doc__', testCaseName)
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

I tried to change the docstring by instantiate it into an object (where `self.__doc__` is writable).

> **UPDATED:** but I want to avoid additional coding
>   in the sub-class (i.e. inheriting
>   super-class function to set docstring
>   of sub-class), for example:

**File DynamicTestCase.py includes:**

```
class DynamicTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setDocstring(self, testCaseDocstring=None):
        if not testCaseDocstring:
            fileName = os.path.split(__file__)[1]
            testCaseDocstring = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]
        setattr(self, '__doc__', testCaseDocstring)
```

**File MyTestCase.py includes:**

```
class MyTestCase(DynamicTestCase):
    def test_print_docstring(self):
        self.setDocstring()
        print 'MyTestCase Docstring = ', self.__doc__
```

But still, the unittest run result is:

```
MyTestCase Docstring = DynamicTestCase
```

When I expected *MyTestCase Docstring = MyTestCase*

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** - `__file__` is the path name from which the *current module* was loaded, so naturally using `__file__` inside DynamicTestCase.py will result in the path DynamicTestCase.py.  However, you can just pass the path into `setDocstring()` from subclasses like this:

**DynamicTestCase.py**:

```
class DynamicTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setDocstring(self, docstring=None):
        if docstring is None:
            docstring = __file__
        if os.path.exists(docstring):
            name = os.path.split(docstring)[1]
            docstring = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
        setattr(self, '__doc__', docstring)
```

**MyTestCase.py**:

```
class MyTestCase(DynamicTestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        DynamicTestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setDocstring(__file__)

    def test_print_docstring(self):
        print 'MyTestCase Docstring = ', self.__doc__

    def test_new_docstring(self):
        self.setDocstring('hello')
        print 'MyTestCase Docstring = ', self.__doc__
```

Output:

```
MyTestCase Docstring =  MyTestCase
MyTestCase Docstring =  hello
```

---

**Rest of answer**

In your original code above `__name__` is a string, not a class. Jython rightly rejects altering the `__doc__` attribute on the `str` type.

Could you explain a bit about *why* you want to change TestCase's docstring?  For example, you could subclass TestCase and give your own docstring:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    "Docstring of MyTestCase"
```

Not sure if you've tried it yet, but the [unittest2 package's](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) TestCase has `setUpClass, tearDownClass` class methods. It's a backport of Python 2.7's improvements to work with Python 2.6 and prior.

Jython allows you to set the `__doc__` of new-style classes, but CPython does not. For that reason you might want to find another way to accomplish your goal if you want your code to be portable:

```
Jython 2.2.1 on java1.6.0_24
>>> unittest.TestCase.__doc__ = 'foo bar'
>>> unittest.TestCase.__doc__
'foo bar'

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 12 2011, 01:07:21)
>>> unittest.TestCase.__doc__ = 'foo bar'
AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

Comment: Thanks samplebias, I tried in the first place to change the TestCase docstring, before adding it's module to the testLoader: `code`(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(testCase))

Comment: But since TestCase __doc__ isn't writable, I'm now trying to do it as you suggested - under the sub-class: `def setDocstring(self):
        fileName = os.path.split(__file__)[1]
        testCaseDocstring = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]
        setattr(self, '__doc__', testCaseDocstring)`         However this function doesn't work either, because when using it, sub-class docstring always gets super-class filename, instead of current sub-class filename.

Comment: I'll update the answer with what I meant by "change it in the subclass of TestCase". Can you give an example of the problem you're trying to solve by changing the docstring of the class?

Comment: Question updated: setting sub-class docstring with current filename - which doesn't work either

Comment: @Noam Check my most recent update above - I modified your `DynamicTestCase.setDocstring` method to work with either a string or a path.

Comment: That is great samplebias, two birds in one shot! You also solved my old nagging error when I tried to use regular `def __init__ (self)` function inside the TestCase Sub-Class, which always failed with: `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. But now No more :)

Comment: @samplebias **Ooops not working actually**, as I was trying to avoid entering in **each** of my TestCase Sub-Classes a Docstring function. is there way to do it without declaring it in MyTestCase.py ?

Answer (score 0):

You are grabbing the filename of the DynamicTestCase file, not the file that is calling the function.  In order to get that you have to go into it's stack frame:

```
  import inspect

  class DynamicTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setDocstring(self, testCaseDocstring=None):
        if not testCaseDocstring:
            fileName = 'unknown.py'

            # Go up one stack frame and grab the file name
            stack = inspect.stack()
            try:
                frame = stack[1][0]
                fileName = frame.f_code.co_filename        
            finally:
                del stack

            testCaseDocstring = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0]
```